# allow ftp to access .htaccess files

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ftp, centos7

First I am a linux newbie. This maybe a very simple thing, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out.

I inherited a server (ubuntu GUI) running a single website + forum. It is currently working perfectly, but is in desperate need of an upgrade to the forum software, which cannot be done on the existing server due to physical constraints. So, I created a new linux VPS on one of my servers using CentOS 7. This is my first time working with linux, but chose CentOS without GUI because I am very technically minded and prefer the command line over the GUI I do not know.

I got LAMP installed and working properly, imported the database dump and got it installed, and am in the process of bringing over the website files.

The problem is my FTP account on the old server cannot see the .htaccess files, and there are a bunch of them in different folders. I need a simple way to allow my ftp account to see and download those files along with everything else (in fact, lets just say I need ALL files, including hidden etc). Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Typically FTP clients follow the *NIX convention of not displaying hidden files, files where the name start with a leading `.` but they should have an option to display such hidden files (such as adding the `-a` flag to the `ls` or `dir` commands. And will also include them when you recursively copy whole directory . It is only very rarely that an FTP server actually blocks access to hidden files.

Comment: TBH I do not know that its not showing hidden... I only know its not showing me the .htaccess files. I will see if filezilla will let me send a optional command of some kind, but I don't recall seeing that option available anywhere.

Comment: Menu --> Server. --> Select Force Showing Hidden Files  (maybe refresh)

Comment: Thanks HBruijn - trying that now. Weird place for that option!

Comment: That option did the trick! Thank you very much! What a PIA lol.

Comment: "Weird place for that option!" - Not really. FileZilla doesn't actually hide dot-files by default (you can enable a "directory listing filter" if you want to hide these files). You shouldn't normally need to enable that "server" option to view dot-files - if you are having to do that then it's because the "server" is explicitly hiding those files (which I don't believe it should "normally" do for FTP), not FileZilla.